# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

currently, I am trying to implement following [Github Tutorial code](https://github.com/nikhilroxtomar/Deep-Residual-Unet/blob/master/Deep%20Residual%20UNet.ipynb) on my local machine. My installed Python and packages are "Python: 3.7.4, tensorflow: 2.1.0, keras: 2.3.1", when i try to run this code..

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = tf.math.reduce_sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.math.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.math.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1.0 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)


model = ResUNet()
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
model.summary()
```

**I get following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-2e02a041e95e> in <module>
      1 model = ResUNet()
      2 adam = keras.optimizers.Adam()
----> 3 model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
      4 model.summary()


**AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'**
```

Comment: Try to pass metrics parameter this way: metrics=['dice_coef', dice_coef]

Comment: I updated line with:

model.compile(loss='dice_coef_loss', optimizer='adam', metrics=['dice_coef', dice_coef])

This time i get error:

ValueError: Unknown loss function:dice_coef_loss